# php get method parameter h=this%20and%20that not working error

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a problem with parameters in php. the result of my browser is page cannot be displayed when the value has an "and" value.

here is the sample

[image]

and when i'm not using the value of "and" the may parameters will work

[image]

when the value has "and" in the middle, i will always get an error as shown from above.

Comment: Along with that art, can we see some code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to pass multiple parameters in get, use different variables:

```
page.php?var1=this&var2=and&var3=that
```

Second, keyword `AND` can be used to inject SQL to your project, so I assume, CI security class will filter this kind of actions.

Third, get rid of html entities like `%20` from your URL, it's ugly, need to parse, and bad practice.

Fourth and most important, CI supports plain GET parameters, but mostly for backwards comparability, CI is MVC framework with own URI structure, where you can pass variables in URI segments instead of in GET elements (they still remain GET variables but CI parses them on it's own way)

Comment: If you submit a <form action=get> with <input type=text name=h value="this and that"/>, then this is the result. Nothing wrong with that. I wouldn't think that he wants to send multiple parameters.

Comment: I can't find anything about form submitting in question.

Comment: No, sorry, my point was that it isn't wrong to have %20 in the query. There is no need to parse it if it actually is entered text you're sending. But if you're right and the op actually wants to send multiple parameters, then you're absolutely right!

Comment: But if so, I would recommend to use ajax instead (although, I haven't used CI). :)